# Is this a scratch or dust in my Nikon D3200 Viewfinder?

Tags: dslr, viewfinder, dust

I recently bought a refurbished Nikon D3200 DSLR and saw this speck in the viewfinder.

My question: is it just dust or a scratch?

(This does not effect my photos- just the viewfinder.)

[image: Viewfinder picture]

Comment: With all of the noise created by the lack of light in your photo it is impossible to say for sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The noisy picture makes it difficult to say, but if it is closer to a round spec, chances are that it is just dust on your viewfinder.

You can follow the steps found here to dismantle your camera to take out and clean it's viewfinder: http://cobytechtutorials.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-opendismantle-your-nikon-d3200.html

Be very careful while following the above steps or else you may end up damaging the camera further! Dismantling the viewfinder will help you find out if it is a dust or a scratch. If it's dust, just clean it; if it is a scratch, I just hope it isn't distracting enough to keep you from clicking nice pictures! Just get it replaced if it's too distracting!

Comment: Unless done in a rigidly controlled "clean room" environment, just the act of taking the camera apart and putting it back together, even if done perfectly, will almost certainly introduce more dust than will be eliminated.

Comment: I agree to that! This needs to be done very carefully and is preferable that this be done by a professional.